# How to get the Oracle external table "dump file" without doing "CREAT TABLE"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a to develop a PL/SQL  procedure that dumps the content of a table when an error occurs during  an  application transaction, the content of the dump must match the content of the table before the ROLLBACK  of the transaction.

I thought about using external table as the dump format of the table (TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP). After going through the Oracle documentation, I found that the only way to that is by executing:

```
CREATE TABLE tabtest_test (
F1 NUMBER,
F2 CHAR(10))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
DEFAULT DIRECTORY USER_DUMP_DEST
LOCATION ('tabtest.dmp’));
```

The problem is that by executing the “CREATE TABLE”, Oracle performs an implicit commit within our failed transaction which needs to be rolled back after the dump of the table.

I thought about using the “PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;” to execute the “CREATE TABLE”, but it doesn’t really fit our need as it dumps the content of the table outside our application transaction.

My question: is there a way to get the 'tabtest.dmp’ without doing a “CREATE TABLE” ? for example by accessing directly the Oracle API responsible for this.

Regards.

Comment: You only need to create the table once. You don't need to do that each time you want to dump the content.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : no, in order get the dmp file we need to create the table each time.

Comment: u need to dump the entire contents every time an error occurs?  u might want to review your requirements, or convince management otherwise.

Comment: @SamiBOB: why do you think you need to run the CREATE TABLE each time? Once it's created you can do an `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` to populate that table.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating the external table once, as part of your application setup process?

Failing that, you could create it at the beginning of the transaction that might need it.  If there is an error, populate it; if the transaction finishes successfully, drop it.

Answer (score 0):

If (and it's a big IF) you can use AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTIONS to create the table in a separate transaction, I think this is what you need to do.  If you manage to create the table within the scope of your current transaction, and write your data to that newly-created table, that data should, by all rights, disappear as soon as you do your ROLLBACK.

The problems you're experiencing here are a subset of the large class of issues known as "Problems Which Occur When Trying To Treat A Relational Database As A Flat File".  Relational databases are great when used AS DATABASES, but are really bad at being flat files.  It's kind of like animals on the farm - sheep are great AS SHEEP, but make lousy cows.  Cows make lousy goats.  Goats - great animals - intelligent, affectionate (yep), low-maintenance, won't hear a word spoken against 'em - but NOT what you want in a draft animal - use a horse, ox, or mule for that.  Basically, you should pick horses for courses (pardon the expression).  A database makes a crappy flat file, and vice versa.  Use what's appropriate.

IMO you'd be better off writing your data to a flat file, and perhaps this file could be mapped in as an external table.  You might want to write the file in something like CSV format that lots of other tools can process.  YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use external tables? You could just read the file using UTL_FILE.